# Default fetchrequest result order changed every time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphonecoredatarecipes

i am simply do a  executedFetchRequest  for an ENtity say @"tanId" it contiains  5 records 1,2,3,4,5

--> problem is first time it shows like  2,3,4,5,1
                                                                                                 --> if again running  it shows like  4,2,1,3,5

super dooper good

any one tell how to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an NSSortDescriptor to sort your NSFetchRequest. Otherwise, order is not guaranteed. There are some examples in the [Fetching Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html) section of the Core Data Programming Guide.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
    initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```